# Fonts are blurry / big in Android Studio

Tags: android, resolution

is there any way I can change the resolution of Android Studio? I looked in Settings->Appearance but it seems like there is no official way to change it. I have a 1920x1080 Display and the whole window and text looks a little bit blurry. I am running a Windows machine on Windows 8.1.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you running on a Windows machine?

Comment: You are looking to change DPI/scaling, not resolution.

Comment: Yes its a Windows machine.

Comment: @Xan Are we both talking about Android Studio itself? Or do you mean the Android device?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to set a compatibility option "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" for the application.

Right-click the taskbar button, then right-click the app name, select Properties, Compatibility. Set the option, save changes, restart Studio.

Those instructions are for a Win7 machine, but Win8.1 should behave the same.

---

To explain what is happening: apparently, the Studio is not "high DPI aware", i.e. does not declare "I know how to handle myself on a high-DPI screen", and Windows tries to scale the window so that its elements do not get too tiny.

You can override this on an app-by-app basis, but be prepared for possible glitches / tiny UI elements.

Comment: I met the same problem on my rMBP15. I migrated Android Studio from a rMBP 13'. but it seems that the IDE uses the old screen resolution(1440x900).so the window is blurry...how can I do to fix it ?

Comment: @Jerry This would be a very different case; I suggest a new question.

Comment: I hope that they will fix Android Studio so that it will work on high dpi and dual screen with other dpi settings. though thanks for this "temp" workaround.

Comment: Great answer. Works on Win10. In my case I also had to change font from monospaced to consolas. Font monospaced was not clear enough especially for bold and/or italic text.

Comment: Thank you so much. ideaC worked fine on a second monitor but android studio did not.
This triggered OCD so bad.

Comment: This solution used to work for me on previous versions of Android Studio, but it is no longer working on the latest release (Electric Eel).

Answer (score 26):

1. Right click on your android studio icon. Go to : Properties -> Compatibility.

[image]

2. Check the "Override high DPI scaling behaviour" option also select "Application" for "Scaling performed by" from the drop down menu.

[image]

3. Press apply and restart your android studio.

Comment: Today I update my Android Studio and scalling stop working. When I set up application compatibility android studio still use system compatibility !! help

Comment: this happens when you use external monitor. and your solution works, thanks. can you share your background image?

Answer (score 10):

I am using Windows 10 and I am facing the same problem.

I know, I know ... why not to switch to Linux? So this won't be a problem..., but the fact is that my company gave me this notebook with Windows :/ and I've been too lazy to format and reinstall OS.

In my case the problem occurs because sometimes I use an external monitor, and sometimes I don't.

When I use the external monitor, the sources are very blurry.

### In my case, what worked was

1. Right click on Studio icon \ Right click on "Android studio" item menu \ Properties
   [image]
2. Compatibility \ Change Settings for all users

[image]

### And now, when using external monitor

3. Check "Run in Compatibility with... Windows 8", and click on Change high DPI settings

[image]

4. Check "Override High DPI with... system"

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: This one worked great!

Answer (score 7):

Modify the font size in the "File > Settings..." screen on Windows

[image: Font size in Android studio]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your PC's theme to Windows 7 Basic. Control Panel>Change Theme. Set it to Windows 7 Basic (should be under the "Basic and High Contrast Themes" header) and see if that fixes it. You may need to restart Android Studio to have the changes take affect. I had this issue too and it bugged the crap out of me and somehow I figured it out. Hope this helps!

Comment: Is this possible for Windows 8.1?

Comment: I'm not sure. Try playing around with some of them and see if one of them works.

Comment: See if you can find some fort of "basic" theme. I'm not running Win 8 but I'm sure there's some sort of equivalent.

Comment: I basically tried every theme but I still have the same problem.
Any other idea? Thank you!