# Text too big in android studio on monitor in windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio

Im running android studio on a surface 4 pro, which has a higher resolution than my desktop monitor.

When i dock the surface, the text in Android studio is massive, and i cant find a way to make it a more acceptable size.

I would appreciate pointers from anyone who has already faced this.

Thanks

Comment: please if you like/can give me some feedback, did my solution worked?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305449/fonts-are-blurry-big-in-android-studio), if does not work, then do ctrl+alt+s and from Keymap assign a combination of keys to enlarge and diminish the text in a class